# Join Query in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I want to create a table C which contains column from Table A (customer_id ) and Table B (customer_id) which contains all customer_id from table A which are not in Table B. I wrote the following query but it didn't get any data populated.

```
create table C AS 
select * 
from (
  select customer_id 
  from A al 
  join B bl 
  on al.customer_id=bl.customer_id 
  where  bl.customer_id is null
) x;
```

This query shows 0 results.

Comment: Maybe no record in B has `bl.customer_id is null` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a1.customer_id 
FROM 
A a1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
B b1 ON a1.customer_id = b1.customer_id 
WHERE b1.customer_id IS NULL;
```

That should do the thing.

Regards,
Dino